# what is the meaning of error syntax error unexpected token near fi

Tags: bash, shell

```
if [ "$var1" = "$var2" ]; then
         if [ -f "$file1" ]; then
       echo "file1 exists"
              if [ -f "$file2" ]; then
                echo "file2 exists"
                 if ["$incValue" == "1"]; then
                    break
                fi
             fi # (I am getting error here!)
            else
                echo "files are not present"
                sleep 300
                
            fi
        else
           echo "files are present"
        fi
```

The above code does'nt works for me. I am getting error as :  syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

I am not able to understand what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That extra `fi` where you see the error is not needed, and it breaks your `if-else` loop. You also need a closing `fi` at the end of your code.

```
if [ "$var1" = "$var2" ]; then
         if [ -f "$file1" ]; then
              echo "file1 exists"
              if [ -f "$file2" ]; then
                 echo "file2 exists"
                 if ["$incValue" == "1"]; then
                    break
                 fi
             else
                echo "files are not present"
                sleep 300 
             fi
        else
           echo "files are present"
        fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a space after the `[` and a space before the `]` in the following line.

`if [ "$incValue" == "1" ]; then`

Comment: This is true, but it should not cause the problem that is presented in the question.